# Removing partial borders with openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm using OpenCV to find tabular data within images so that I can use an OCR on it. So far I have been able to find the table in the image, find the columns of the table, then find each cell within each column. It works pretty well, but I'm having an issue with the cell walls getting stuck in my images and I'm unable to remove them reliably.[This is one example that I'm having difficulty with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clpc7.png)[This would be another example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFRLN.png)

I have tried several approaches to get these images better. I have been having the most luck with finding the contours.

```
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image_final = cv2.bitwise_and(img2gray, img2gray, mask=mask)
ret, new_img = cv2.threshold(image_final, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (5, 3))

# dilate , more the iteration more the dilation
dilated = cv2.dilate(new_img, kernel, iterations=3)
cv2.imwrite('../test_images/find_contours_dilated.png', dilated)
```

I have been toying with the kernel size and dilation iterations and have found this to be the best configuration.

Another approach I used was with PIL, but it is only really good if the border is uniform around the whole image, which in my cases it is not.

```
copy = Image.fromarray(img)
try:
    bg = Image.new(copy.mode, copy.size, copy.getpixel((0, 0)))
except:
    return None
diff = ImageChops.difference(copy, bg)
diff = ImageChops.add(diff, diff, 2.0, -100)
bbox = diff.getbbox()
if bbox:
    return np.array(copy.crop(bbox))
```

There were a few other ideas that I tried, but none got me very far. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with finding contours and "drawing" them out. Meaning you can draw a border that will be connected with the "walls" mannualy with `cv2.rectangle` on the borders of your image (that will combine all contours - walls). The biggest two contours will be outer and inner line of your walls and you can draw the contour white to remove the border. Then apply threshold again to remove the rest of the noise. Cheers!

Example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read the image
img = cv2.imread('borders2.png')

# Get image shape
h, w, channels = img.shape

# Draw a rectangle on the border to combine the wall to one contour
cv2.rectangle(img,(0,0),(w,h),(0,0,0),2)

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply binary threshold
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Search for contours and sort them by size
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
area = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

# Draw it out with white color from biggest to second biggest contour
cv2.drawContours(img, ((contours[0]),(contours[1])), -1, (255,255,255), -1)

# Apply binary threshold again to the new image to remove little noises
_, img = cv2.threshold(img, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Display results
cv2.imshow('img', img)
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Amazing, works great. For some reason it wouldn't find the inner contour of the borders for me. I just assumed a 10 pixel border and it works pretty well.

Comment: Am glad it helped...there are a lot of possibilities how to remove...one that I posted or only draw white rectangle with thick border or simply croping the image by few pixels